# Word that means "do research online"

Tags: single-word-requests

There was a word I heard a long time ago in a video game that sounded something like "sleuthering", and when I looked it up it meant "to search or do research online" or something like that. I can't find this word now... The closest word I found is "sleuthing"; the meaning is close but it's not the same word.

Does anyone have any idea? The video game is Metal Gear Solid 4, and the sentence went something like "Sunny did some 'sleuthering' for us and...."

I can't look up cutscenes of the game because this line was spoken during an in-game "codec" call.

Comment: "Sleuthing" from verb "sleuth" which means to investigate, it can be any sort of investigation, including online.

Comment: Yeah but the word stuck in my head(its shadow, at least) because somehow I found out it meant specifically to research online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found dialog [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/926596-metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-the-patriots/faqs/53154):

Snake            : What's your take on him, Otacon?

Otacon           : I don't particularly like the guy, but it looks like we'll
                   need his help with those ID guns. Sunny's been doing a
                   little **sleuthing** for us. Drebin. A well-known gun launderer
                   in war economy circles. He's a businessman who deals mainly
                   in selling black-market firearms to small PMCs and local
                   militia. Somalia, the Balkans, Lebanon, Darfur, Chechnya,
                   Timor, Peru, the Punjab, Kashmir, Colombia. This guy really
                   gets around.

So the word is exact thus that your remember. =)

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder where the part about "research online" came from then. Maybe I'm just getting old.